# Can't install GNOME on Fedora Server 31

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to install GNOME on Fedora Server 31. `dnf` keeps responding with

> failed to download metadata for "fedora-modular".

Is `dnf` just broken?

I tried using:

```
dnf -y group install "Basic Desktop" GNOME
dnf group install "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

and a few others but all have a problem with fedora-modular.

I just downloaded Fedora Server 31 (3/30).

Comment: Have you tried `dnf clean all` before running it?

Comment: Typo : group install .... The command is `# dnf groupinstall " .. "` ... I.e. groupinstall is not two words.

Comment: Nasir & Knud: Thanks for the response. I ran dnf clean all before trying the corrected dnf.  It removed a few files and exited correctly. The corrected dnf command still does not like "fedora-modular". Failed to download metadata for that repo.